# Nlog direct access working but not PostSharp default

Tags: postsharp

I'm new in learning about how PostSharp works. I've written some code using NLog that I want to improve using PostSharp.

- The Nlog output is working (output is done both on console & file).
- The PostSharp isn't working at all (no output to file, no output console).

I tried to follow to documentation from PostSharp website : https://doc.postsharp.net/nlog

I don't understand where my mistake is :(

Can somebody give me a little hand to solve this problem ?

Thanks for help.

```
using System;
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Backends.NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using System.Text;
using NLog;
using LogLevel = PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.LogLevel;
using static PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.FormattedMessageBuilder;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    static class LogSources
    {
        // Configure a prototype LogSource that you will reuse in several classes.
        public static readonly LogSource Default = LogSource.Get().WithLevels(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Warning);
    }

    /// <summary>
/// Main class
/// </summary>
[Log]
class Program 
{
    static LoggingConfiguration config;
    static readonly LogSource logSource = LogSource.Get().WithLevels(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Warning);

    /// <summary>
    /// MAIN ENTRY
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        InitNLog(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables (@"%TEMP%\MyLog.txt"));
        InitPostSharp();

        LogMe();

        logSource.Default.Write (Formatted("This is a TEST message"));
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Trace("This is a Trace message");
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Debug("This is a Debug message");
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("This is an Info message");
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Warn("This is a Warn message");
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Error("This is an Error message");
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Fatal("This is a Fatal error message");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [Log]
    public static void LogMe()
    {
        logSource.Default.Write(Formatted("pleassseee loggggg meeeee"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes PostSharp.
    /// </summary>
    private static void InitPostSharp()
    {
        LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new NLogLoggingBackend(new LogFactory(config));

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Init NLog system
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outputFileName">Full path for output logging file.</param>
    static void InitNLog(string outputFileName)
    {
        // NLOG CONFIGURATION - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial
        // Step 1. Create configuration object 
        config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // Step 2. Create targets and add them to the configuration 
        ColoredConsoleTarget consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();

        consoleTarget.Layout = @"${date:universalTime=true:format=HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${message} ${exception:format=Message}";
        consoleTarget.UseDefaultRowHighlightingRules = false;
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Clear();
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level == LogLevel.Trace and starts-with('${message}','[THREAD:')", ConsoleOutputColor.Cyan, ConsoleOutputColor.Black));
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level == LogLevel.Trace", ConsoleOutputColor.DarkCyan, ConsoleOutputColor.Black));
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level == LogLevel.Debug", ConsoleOutputColor.DarkGray, ConsoleOutputColor.Black));
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level == LogLevel.Info", ConsoleOutputColor.White, ConsoleOutputColor.Black));
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level == LogLevel.Warn", ConsoleOutputColor.Yellow, ConsoleOutputColor.Black));
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level == LogLevel.Error", ConsoleOutputColor.Red, ConsoleOutputColor.Black));
        consoleTarget.RowHighlightingRules.Add(new ConsoleRowHighlightingRule("level >= LogLevel.Fatal", ConsoleOutputColor.White, ConsoleOutputColor.DarkRed));
        consoleTarget.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

        FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
        fileTarget.FileName = outputFileName;

        // Step 3. Set target properties 
        consoleTarget.Layout = "${logger}|${message}";
        fileTarget.Layout = "${machinename}|${longdate}|${logger}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}|${exception:separator=\r\n:format=message,type,method,stackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10:innerExceptionSeparator=\r\n:innerFormat=message,type,method,stackTrace}";

        // Step 4. Define rules
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, consoleTarget));
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget));

        // Step 5. Activate the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
        LogManager.EnableLogging();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp only logs methods annotated with `[Log]` and it only starts logging after you set the backend, which you did in `InitPostSharp`.

If you add to your class `Program` the following method:

```
[Log]
public static void LogMe() 
{
}
```

and call `LogMe()` from `Main` after `InitPostSharp`, it will be logged into NLog.

A problem with your code is also this line:
`[Log(AttributeExclude=true)]` which means "remove logging" (because of the `AttributeExclude`). If you instead use simply `[Log]`, the attribute will multicast down on all methods of the class, including LogMe. Still, methods calls that started before you set up the backend in InitPostSharp will not be affected.

Comment: I ran your code with the changes I said and the PostSharp logging data was written on the console. You could edit your code in the question with your changes and I can look again.

Comment: a slight progression. I've added this to GlobalAspect.cs :
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 1, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Protected | MulticastAttributes.Internal | MulticastAttributes.Public)]
[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 2, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetMembers = "get_*")]
It logs Starting & Succeeded but not the message inside

Comment: Your code prints "Starting and Succeeded" as written in your question for me, even without the stuff in GlobalAspect.cs. As for the message inside, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480326/postsharp-does-not-log-on-trace-level

Comment: But why the content of the LogMe() is not logged ? I think I messed something. PostSharp can use NLog but not intended to replace it everywhere Nlog is used ? Am i right ?

Comment: The content of LogMe() is not logged because you're outputting at the level Trace (because in your LogSource initialization you set Trace as the default). PostSharp by default doesn't output any Trace logging. To make PostSharp output stuff even at the Trace level, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480326/postsharp-does-not-log-on-trace-level